# viewport scale doesn't work after orientation change

Tags: javascript, ios, html, scale, viewport

I use the following function to rescale my viewport on iPad:

```
function rescale(scale){
 var headElements = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    for(var i = 0; i< headElements.length; i++){
    var theElement = headElements[i];
    if(theElement.name == "viewport"){
      theElement.content = "width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=" + scale + ", maximum-scale=" + scale + ";";

    }     
  }
}
```

This works an unlimited number of times (in either portrait or landscape orientation), *until* I change the orientation of the device, when it ceases to work until i reload the page.

Is this a bug in iOS, or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems until I started cutting down on parameters and came down to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I suspect there's something to do with `user-scalable=no` part, since when you change orientation the viewport width is changed. But try the code above first and take it from there.

I don't think `maximum-scale` plays too well with orientation either, so try with and without it after removing the `user-scalable` parameter.